# setting state in functional component. (object in array that is in object)

Tags: reactjs

```js
  const [post, setPost] = useState({
    title: '',
    rolepair: [{name: '', job: ''}],
    industry: '',
    due_at: '',
    content: '',
  });
```

If I want to set data into `post.rolepair[0].name`, How could I do?
I tried

```js
setPost({...post, rolepair[0].source : newData});
setPost({...post, rolepair: post.rolepair[0].source(newData)});
setPost({...post, rolepair[0]: sorce : newData});
```

non of them worked though.

Answer (score 2):

Map the `rolepair` property to a new array, and at the first index, add a new `name` property with the conditional operator:

```
setPost({
  ...post,
  rolepair: post.rolepair.map(
    (obj, i) => i === 0
      ? { ...obj, name: newData }
      : obj
  )
});
```

Comment: what is `:obj` at the end for?

Comment: `cond ? expr1 : expr2` is the conditional operator. It evaluates to `expr1` if `cond` is truthy. Otherwise it evaluates to `expr2`.

Comment: ohhh oh my god.. I got it Thank you!!